# How do you fix error: Icon stream is not in the expected format

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the following error:

> BC30136 Error creating Win32 resource: Icon stream is not in the expected format.

I have researched this, tried deleting all the icons that I have in the project, but to no avail. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Post your code in the question, and provide the error as text, not screenshot.

Comment: In addition to Racil's comment, what technology are you using: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, Console, (other)?

Comment: This is the code that I think could be the problem:                              
Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon). I am not sure if that is what is causing the problem though. And I am using winforms

Comment: Some that has experienced this have had too little space left on their HDD. Verify that you have at least 1 GB free (which is extremely little these days, but it is at least enough for your application to compile) and ensure that all referenced icons in your project actually are of the [**ICO format**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)).

Comment: Also verify that you're not trying to load any icons where an image (BMP, PNG, JPG, etc.) is expected.

Comment: I have checked both the space on the HDD and the format of the referenced icons, and still nothing. I will keep looking for other references to icons, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Good luck. Unfortunately these kinds of problems are hard to diagnose (especially for us that cannot reproduce it). If you don't manage to track down the source of the problem, create a new project and import every piece of your code file-by-file from the old one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/error-creating-win32-resources-error-message and also check that the image you are trying to load isn't compressed

Comment: Update the .ico file was saved as an .ico file but was not in the correct format. If you have the same issue, make sure that the file is actually in the format of an .ico file.

Comment: Glad you found the cause! You ought to write that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: need detail of what you had try to solve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .ico file was saved as an .ico file but was not in the correct format. If you have the same issue, make sure that the file is actually in the format of an .ico file

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the binary file is in GIT LFS, but was not checked out from LFS.

In TFS or Azure DevOps, edit the build pipeline. There is a step called 'Get source'. Configure it to clean the build directories and to checkout LFS.

[image]